# How to set a $scope variable from inside another scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code, and I am trying to set the value of a `$scope` variable after a promise (in this case an `$http` request) is finished.  The code looks like this:

```
.controller('NewItemCtrl', function ($scope, $state, LabelFactory) {

  $scope.createItem = function (item) {
    LabelFactory.createLabel(item)
      .then(function (response) {
        $scope.label = response.data;
        $scope.thing = 'These are things';
        $state.go('tab.newitem-label');
        console.log($scope.label);  
      });  
  };
})
```

And it looks like it should work but it doesn't.  Even though I am able to log `$scope.label` correctly, when I look for that item in my template (for which `NewItemCtrl` is the controller), nothing is there.  It is as if I never sent it at all, even though it obviously has a value.

Can someone explain to me how to either **A.** Set the value of`$scope` property from inside another scope,or **B.**  the best practice to achieve the same thing?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes check this link which is great article about how scope is working...

Comment: write  console.log($scope.label); then  $state.go('tab.newitem-label'); because you are redirecting.

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi the `console.log` part is not what is important - setting the `$scope` value  for use elsewhere in the app is.

Comment: @Startec if you change state controller start again which means old values is gone. if you want to pass parameters between controllers use services which are singletons

Comment: ahh, I see. @wickY26, there is really no simpler way?

Comment: @Startec actually it is very simple let me prepare a plunker for you.

Comment: @Startec here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/g3IdL8?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are going to another state which recreates the scope object.

One way to achieve this is to use a hierarchical state. A child scope can access scope of its parent state. Since you are going to 'tab.newitem-label', if you are at state 'tab' before going to this new state, setting `label` in scope of `tab` state will be enough to access it from `tab.newitem`.

I believe you are using `ui-router`. Then you might make this label part of existing state. The parameterized value can be accessed through `$stateParams`. So instead of moving to `$state.go('tab.newitem-label');`, you might pass your parameter to new state using the following syntax: `$state.go('tab.newitem-label', {labelId: labelId});` Then you can access `labelId` parameter using `$stateParams.labelId` in your controller and before creating your controller you can retrieve the label using `labelId` by `resolve` feature of state. `Resolve` feature helps you retrieve date before instantiating your controller. You can then inject the resolved data to your controller similar to injecting service to your controller.

This is how you might define such a state:

```
.state('tab.newitem-label', {
        url: '/:labelId',
        templateUrl: 'partials/yourpage.html',
        controller: 'NewStateCtrl'
        resolve: {
          label: ['labelService', '$stateParams', function (labelService, $stateParams) {
            return labelService.retrieveLabelFromLabelId($stateParams.labelId);
          }]
        }
      })
```

Comment: This seems like the best way. I am new to `ui-router` (you are right, I am using that), so thanks for this guidance.

Answer (score 0):

you can put  a watch over the {$scope.label} and see if the new value update is triggering the watch function to executes.once you confirm the update is triggering the watch ,use the function to update all the places/controllers where  {$scope.label} is been used probably using a $emit/$broadcast